# How can I make f=x at the end

Tags: python

Im trying to make an equilateral triangle and I need the triangle be the size of the user's choosing and I need to add a square after it to make it into an arrow. The square needs to be relative to the size of the triangle so it will actually look like and arrow, I would need the f to equal x

```
def square(f):
 å=" "
 p= f-1
 x=int(input("Give size"))
 y=input("Give symbol")
 y=y+" "
 for c in range(x):
     print("\n",y*x)
 for s in range(x):
     print(y*s)
 print("\n")
 for i in range(0,f):    
     for l in range(0, p):
         print(end=" ")
     p=p-1
     for l in range(0, i+1):
         print(y,end="")
     print("\r")
 x=x//2
 for b in range(0,x):
     print(å*5+y*x)
f=9
square(f)
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Please add some details to your question: Do you get any errors? What output do you expect? ...? It is very hard to help you without exactly knowing what you try to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

Literally half of your code is unnecessary regarding the question. I have reformatted the valid parts to a sample code, which does what you're asking ("drawing an equilateral triangle with the size of user's choosing"). You had the code already working there though so I'm not sure what the issue was. In any case, try to format your code better especially when asking other developers for help. Using non-explanatory variable names and generally other than English language is disorienting to read and discouraged.

```
def draw_triangle(width):
    symbol = input("Input a symbol: ")
    p = width - 1
    for i in range(0, width):    
        for _ in range(0, p):
            print(end=" ")
        p = p - 1
        for _ in range(0, i + 1):
            print(symbol + " ", end="")
        print("\r")

width = 9
draw_triangle(width)
```